# Displayed Encrypt Page in SWT Browser

Tags: browser, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am using SWT Browser to display html pages. These HTML pages are stored in a folder. By this anybody can copy the data easily, which I want to protect. For this I have encrypted the HTML pages.

How to decrypt these HTML pages during `Backward` and `Forward` activity ? Also while displaying them in the browser by using setUrl("url") method -

`htmlBrowser.setUrl(url String);`